# Custom RouteContraint with IOptions

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, route-constraint

Is there a way to pass IOptions into a custom IRouteConstraint? I'm trying to check an appsetting to see if I need to have a certain route or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't find any references in the moment, but

1. either it works when you pass it in the constructor (I assume you tried it and it didn't work)
2. get it from the `HttpContext`, which is passed to the `Match` method

Example:

```
public class MyConstraint : IRouteConstraint
{
    public bool Match(HttpContext httpContext, IRouter route, string routeKey, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        var options = httpContext.RequestServices.GetService<IOptions<MySettings>>();

        return ...;
    }
}
```

Comment: I did try it in the constructor. I'll try grabbing it from the httpContext. Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working. I can't specify the type. Still looking.

Comment: Got it. Here's what I did:

`...
var options = httpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(IOptions<MySettings>));
...`

Comment: I prefer the generic versions where possible. For it you need to add a `using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;` to make the generic extension methods available